# Python: RecursionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Каждый раз, запуская вот такой код:

```python
from _ctypes import FUNCFLAG_STDCALL
from _ctypes import CFuncPtr
from _ctypes import LoadLibrary
from _ctypes import Structure, pointer
from _ctypes import _SimpleCData

class c_long(_SimpleCData):
    _type_ = "l"
class c_int(_SimpleCData):
    _type_ = 'i'

class WinDLL(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        import nt
        LibraryLoader = LoadLibrary(name, nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS)
        class WinDLL_Func(CFuncPtr):
            _flags_ = FUNCFLAG_STDCALL
            _restype_ = c_int
        self.WinDLL_Func = WinDLL_Func
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.WinDLL_Func((name, self))

class POINT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('x', c_long),
                ('y', c_long)]
pointerpoint = pointer(POINT())
user32 = WinDLL('user32')
user32.GetCursorPos(pointerpoint)
print('({}, {})'.format(pointerpoint[0].x, pointerpoint[0].y))
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyG.py", line 25, in <module>
    user32.GetCursorPos(pointer(POINT()))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyG.py", line 18, in __getattr__
    return self.WinDLL_Func((name, self))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyG.py", line 18, in __getattr__
    return self.WinDLL_Func((name, self))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\PyG.py", line 18, in __getattr__
    return self.WinDLL_Func((name, self))
  [Previous line repeated 510 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: отформатируйте код нормально. все import'ы должны быть сверху, между классами и функциями должны быть пустые строки. такой код невозможно читать

Comment: @timur, субъективно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Понятия не имею, что делает этот код...

Но вот такое например решение (только будьте острожны, не делайте `LIMIT` слишком большим!):

```
import sys
LIMIT = 1000
sys.setrecursionlimit(LIMIT) # or more than 1000...
```

Я на линуксе, так что попробовать не могу...

И кстати если это по сути функция без условия выхода типа:

```
def f():
    ...
    f()
```

То нет смысла пытаться делать, то что я предложил, лучше скажите что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Victor VosMottor, в моём коде я объявил класс WinDLL, который импортирует библиотеку, благодаря глобальной функнции LoadLibrary, в данном случае - user32. Затем я избавляюсь от ошибки AttributeError в user32.GetCursorPos(pointer(POINT())) , используя функцию ```__getattr__```. ```__getattr__``` ссылается на функцию WinDLL_Func, которая использует глобальную функцию CFuncPtr, как метод. При попытке рекурсии(return self.WinDLL_Func((name, self))) и появляется ошибка. И я до сих пор не могу понять, как это исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Я забыл про ещё одну глобальную переменную - _handle.

```
LibraryLoader = LoadLibrary(name, nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS)
```

Нужно заменить на

```
self._handle = LoadLibrary(name, nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS)
```

В результате получается, то что я и задумал: DLL библиотека user32 передаёт данные о позиции курсора в указатель, а затем данные выводятся на экран